# Trigger function when button is clicked but before submission

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit, mouseenter

I am swapping out the contents of one wysiwyg editor into another before submission. I have been doing this by wrapping the submit button in a div and using the mouseenter event to fire it.

```
<div id="moveit">
<input type="button" name="sq_commit_button" id="sq_commit_button" value="Commit" accesskey="s" class="sq-form-field sq-btn-large sq-btn-green sq-commit-button" onclick="if (submit_form) { submit_form(this.form); } else { this.form.submit(); this.disabled = 'disabled';}  ">
</div>
```

and

```
jQuery('#moveit').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery('#news_item_0_1162_wysiwyg_div #htmlarea iframe').contents().find('html').html(jQuery('#cke_1_contents iframe').contents().find('html body').html());
});
```

This has worked just fine for now, but is by no means a long term solution. Is there a way to execute the function when the button is clicked but before it submits, so the content can be copied across?

I tried using the onsubmit function, but when I look, the wysiwyg editor doesn't seem to consist of any form elements.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

The only instance of a form on the page looks like this, and I have tried the following form id and name in an onsubmit function without any luck.

```
<form id="page_asset_builder_1427599" name="main_form" method="post" action="http://example.com/builder/_nocache?" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return form_on_submit()">
```

Can anyone suggest how I could do this? Or should I just stick with my mouseenter method and try and forget about it

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the onclick from your button and using this jquery. This is assuming that your button is in the form.

```js
$(document).on("click","#sq_commit_button",function() {
  // your pre submit code here
  $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Mate that actually worked perfectly, Thank you for your input